# Moving files from Tomcat Linux to another Linux Server

Tags: java, linux, file, tomcat

I've taken a job where years ago their webmaster setup an intranet using Tomcat on a linux server. The users can create something in the test environment and then click "make live" and the Linux/Tomcat moves the file to a Linux/live PHP web setup.

I'm clueless how they're moving the files. What would be a common tool to do this in Tomcat and Java?

I realize this is vague, but any help would be appreciated. Let me know what other info would be needed.

Also there is a duplicate MySQL database in both servers. I'm guessing the Tomcat setup is writing duplicate info to both databases, but I don't see how the files are getting moved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like the website content is completely stored in the database and written over to the other server.

Theoretically you could also have a rsync shell script and call that from php to actually synchronize files over to the other server.

If the "Make Live" is on click and happens immediately its either a direct db access or some script based synchronization.

If it takes a while it could be a cron-job. Maybe you should just check this anway crontab -l will work.

There are several options, you actually open the *.php which the user can edit the content and see where the make live button brings you e.g. "Post Form to *.php" and than you check what that script is doing or you show us the package (what i would like to see but not suggest if you are working on a companies site).

Get back here with some more information, so i can expand the answer for you. Maybe you should also clarify why you are clueless, state what you have checked already, the info i would require is the actual site which has the make live button on it, it will lead to the next site or a script which will probably show what the site is doing.

Comment: Oliver Thanks for responding to a unique question. I was able to track everything the PHP/MySQL was doing, but my confusion came from most of this being done in Java and ASP on a Linux machine. Not something I'm familiar with. After posting I found a MoveLive.java file buried that I was able to get the needed sftp user and pass from that and added to them to other Linux server users. After that, everything was able to talk again. It seems to be connecting to the MySQl and sftp all through Java and moving the physical files that way. Strange setup, but everything is working again. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey Jameson, no worries, most of the time the mental assistance and some keywords can make sure another idea drops into your head and you start to snoop around at the right places :-)